# Rotating a lead screw with a moving magnet

Tags: magnets

Is it possible to introduce torque on a lead screw (with no magnets attached to it) with a moving magnet that can only move parallels to the screw?

(the lead screw is ferromagnetic)

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: I can't see why not, as long as your magnet is strong enough and surrounding components aren't magnetic.

Comment: I edit my question, is there a magnetic configuration to do that with the magnet moving parallels to the screw?

Comment: all motors are basically rotating a magnet around a shaft, so this is just a different application.  But you will find that low speed isn't the sweet spot for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is POSSIBLE but it's not very practical.

Take a look at how **switched reluctance motors** work.   Essentially, torque is generated by the motion of the soft magnetic material to align itself with the magnetic field lines.   You're using a hard magnetic material (ferromagnetic), but the approach is essentially the same.

IT would work a lot better if you can introduce some level of asymmetry  to your screw cross sectional area, but if you don't want to do that, you can get an effective elongated magnetic profile by aligning your stators with the thread pitch of your screw.

Comment: I'm not sure i fully understood.
I updated the original question, can you further elaborate on your proposal?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/52qBWZt

Comment: that's geniuses. did you saw a video of someone actually doing it? i would love to see it, cant find any

also, if i change the polarity of one of the magnets, will it unscrew?

Comment: btw, can you suggest a drawing for the asymmetry that you talked about?
maybe i can do it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JVwVcLy
Upvotes please if you find this helpful

Comment: I marked as answered thanks!

so something like that will work better?
https://imgur.com/ex9IKIu
(tooth like, not 3d along the line)

also - is there a way to unscrew it but keeping the magnets move from left to right as with the screw config?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  magnetic materials are much more magnetically permeable than air.  The universe wants to minimize the length of magnetic field lines.  So, if you have a chunk of metal on an axis of rotation, the chunk of metal will rotate to make the universe happy.